# Getting PID from running bat script

Tags: batch-file, pid

Hi i'm trying to find a way to get my own PID from a bat script.
I found this:

```
title=mycmd
tasklist /v /fo csv | findstr /i "mycmd"
```

that outputs:

```
"cmd.exe","15084","RDP-Tcp#5","2","2,768 K","Running","MEDIASERVER\Administrator
","0:00:00","Administrator: =mycmd"
```

how would I get the PID number into a variable in my bat script?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with [getcmdpid](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/getCmdPID.bat) , thus you will not need to change the title:

```
call getCmdPID.bat
echo %errorlevel%
```

to do it with tasklist you'll need for loop to process the output:

```
title mycmd
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (
  'tasklist /v /fo csv ^| findstr /i "mycmd"'
) do (
  set "mypid=%%~a"
)
echo %mypid%
```

check also this thread:
http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6133

Answer (score 5):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Prepare a temporary file reference where to send the wmic output
    for %%t in ("%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%.tmp") do > "%%~ft" (

        rem Call wmic to retrieve its own parent process ID, that is, our cmd instance
        wmic process where "name='wmic.exe' and commandline like '%%_%random%%random%%random%_%%'" get parentprocessid

        rem Read the PID from the generated temporary file
        for /f "skip=1" %%a in ('type "%%~ft"') do set "processID=%%a"

        rem And remove the temporary file
    ) & 2>nul del /q "%%~ft"

    echo %processID%
```